# How do I create a new table using columns from existing tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables, Test1 and Test2, and I want to create another table, Test3 using columns that are keys from Test1 and Test2.

I'm trying to find the right syntax, but can't figure out how.
I've done (SELECT Person_ID FROM Test1) and that hasn't worked.

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
    Person_ID VARCHAR(10) key,
    First_Name VARCHAR(20),
    Last_Name VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Test2 (
    Card_ID VARCHAR(20) key,
    Date_Issued DATE
)

#what I tried
CREATE TABLE Test3 (
    ID INT key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Person_ID (SELECT Person_ID FROM Test1),
    Card_ID (SELECT Card_ID FROM Test2)
)
```

So in the end, I'm getting an ERROR 1064 (42000) which tells me there's an error in my syntax. What I want is if Person_ID from Test1 is 10010, then Person_ID in Test3 would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense.  If you want a Cartesian product of the two tables, you can use a view:

```
create view v_table3 as
    select t1.person_id, t2.card_id
    from test1 t1 cross join
         test2 t2;
```

If you want an increasing counter, use `row_number()`:

```
create view v_table3 as
    select row_number() over (order by t1.person_id, t2.card_id) as id,
           t1.person_id, t2.card_id
    from test1 t1 cross join
         test2 t2;
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you might just want to declare a foreign key relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE Test3 (
    ID INT key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Person_ID int, (SELECT Person_ID FROM Test1),
    Card_ID int,
    foreign key (person_id) references test1(person_id), 
    foreign key (card_id) references test2(card_id)
);
```